# ControlsFX. SpreadSheetView. How do hide row or change row height?

Tags: java, javafx, controlsfx

I can not hide a row or change its height.

I try:

```
GridBase grid = (GridBase) spreadSheetView.getGrid();
grid.setRowHeightCallback(index -> {
    return 0.0;
});
```

But this only works when the SpreadSheetView component is initialized. And I need to change the height of the line (or hide it) in the already drawn component.
Attempt to change the height of the graphics cells did not lead to anything.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide a row inside the SpreadsheetView, simply call "hideRow" with the row index as it is described in the javadoc : https://controlsfx.bitbucket.io/org/controlsfx/control/spreadsheet/SpreadsheetView.html#hideRow-int-